# Ideas for Obj-C/cocoa interface between file-based stream data processing elements

Tags: macos, cocoa

For a Mac OS/cocoa app, I would like to read a file, do a variable number of different processing functions to the data stream, and write the result to another file. This is really just a protocol stack. The controlling object would create data processing objects (elements) and link them together with the first element reading data from the file in arbitrary sized blocks, then invoking the next element in the stack to do whatever it needs to do to the data, and so on until the final element that writes the data to the output file. Like System-V streams, but in user space.

The first thing that comes to mind is a set of classes that each adheres to a protocol with methods to initialize, read data from the stream, write data to the stream and flush or close the stream. Each element would need to have an (id) pointer to the next element, which would be set up at initialization. NSStream sounded promising, but it seems geared toward a single source/sink of data, not pushing data processing elements on a protocol stack. The NSStreamDelegate protocol has only - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent

Does anything exist to do this? Any better suggestions for the interface and implementation?

Comment: you can subclass NSStream ... you can make t's and open new output streams to file based pipes or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GCD `dispatch_io_read` to asynchronously process the data from the file, process the data in the handler block, and then use `dispatch_io_write` to asynchronously write the data to the file.

As you obviously know, SVr4 streams use modules, and each module can process the data in a chain of function calls, or place the message on a queue to be processed by another thread of control.  That thread of control is basically a message queue.

You can accomplish almost the same thing using GCD dispatch queues.  If you want to configure them ahead of time and have a bit more control over their execution, take a look at `NSOperationQueue`.

**EDIT**

Since you expressed interest in a SVr4 STREAMS-ish API, I can give this untested trifle of code.  It allows you to push tasks on a stream, and then put/putnext a piece of data.

A sync operation executes synchronously, in the thread of the caller.  And async operation executes asynchronously, using GCD.  NOTE: This is just a suggestion I hacked up, but it should give you some idea...  it is in no way indicative of the real STREAMS API, but if you are looking for something like that, this should help get you there if you don't want to use `NSOperation` and friends.

Headers...

```
@class Task;
typedef void(^TaskBlock)(Task *task, NSData *data);
@interface Task : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name
                        next:(Task*)nextTask
                       block:(TaskBlock)block;
- (void)put:(NSData*)data;
- (void)putNext:(NSData *)data;
@end
@interface STREAM : NSObject
@end
```

Implementation...

```
@implementation Task {
  dispatch_queue_t _queue;
  TaskBlock _block;
  Task *_next;
}
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name
                        next:(Task*)nextTask
                       block:(TaskBlock)block
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    if (name) {
      _queue = dispatch_queue_create(
          [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
          DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    _block = block;
    _next = nextTask;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)put:(NSData*)data
{
  if (_queue) {
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
      _block(self, data);
    });
  } else {
    _block(self, data);
  }
}

- (void)putNext:(NSData *)data
{
  if (_next) {
    [_next put:data];
  }
}
@end



@implementation STREAM {
  Task *_head;
}
- (instancetype)init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _head = [[Task alloc] initWithName:nil
                                  next:nil
                                 block:^(Task *module, NSData *data) {
      // Do nothing
    }];
  }
  return self;
}
- (STREAM*)pushSyncBlock:(TaskBlock)block
{
  _head = [[Task alloc] initWithName:nil next:_head block:block];
  return self;
}
- (STREAM*)pushAsyncBlock:(TaskBlock)block
{
  _head = [[Task alloc] initWithName:@"STREAMTaskQueue"
                                next:_head
                               block:block];
  return self;
}
- (void)put:(NSData *)data
{
  [_head put:data];
}
@end
```

And a sample usage...

```
STREAM *stream = [[STREAM alloc] init];
[[[[stream pushAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the LAST block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the THIRD block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushSyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the SECOND block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the FIRST block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}];

[stream put:nil];
```

The STREAMS API always pushes modules onto the stream, but you can change the API to something where the above code is in proper order by doing something like...

```
[[[[stream pushFrontAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the FIRST block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushFrontAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the SECOND block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushFrontSyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the THIRD block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}] pushFrontAsyncBlock:^(Task *task, NSData *data) {
  // Do something with the data -- this is the LAST block executed
  [task putNext:data];
}];
```

Comment: I will certainly need to use (a) separate thread(s) to prevent the spinning beach ball. Unless I am missing something, I do not see a way, using GCD methods, to chain together a variable number of processing elements such that the output of one becomes the input of the other. GCD dispatch_io_* methods take a single handler and don't define a protocol to allow that handler to invoke other handlers. Since the user specifies what needs to be done, the choice of elements is a run-time decision.

Comment: You pass in the handler as a block, and that block can do anything.  You also give it a queue to use for the operation, which does not have to be the main queue.  Thus, you can do it all without ever touching the main thread which is where the GUI is running.

I would also re-suggest looking at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` which have most of everything you want from your SVr4 STREAMS API.  Looks specifically at adding operation dependencies.